# PSTricks : draw a cross

Tags: pstricks, standalone

I would like to draw a cross at a specific position. I already know how to draw a circle with

```
\pscircle[...](x,y){...}
```

is there something as simple that doesn't require any other package.

For now I only use `pstricks-add` in a `standalone` document class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example an easy and a more complex solution:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm,pstricks]{standalone}
\makeatletter
\def\psCross{\pst@object{psCross}}
\def\psCross@i(#1)#2{%
    \begin@SpecialObj
    \pst@dima=#2
    \rput{\psk@gangle}(#1){\psline(-0.5\pst@dima,0)(0.5\pst@dima,0)%
                  \psline(0,-0.5\pst@dima,0)(0,0.5\pst@dima,0)}%
    \end@SpecialObj}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-3,-3)(3,3)
\psdot[dotsize=4cm,dotstyle=x](0,0)
\end{pspicture}

\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-3,-3)(3,3)
\psCross(-2,-2){1cm}
\psCross[linecolor=red,linewidth=2pt,gangle=45](0,0){2cm}
\psCross[linecolor=blue,linewidth=6pt,strokeopacity=0.4,gangle=60](0,1){4cm}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: nice answer thank you ! I also ended up using 2 `pslines` but I hoped there was already something defined. Your answer defines this... so thanks again